# Jtable column render

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, tablemodel

I've got a table with three columns. Columns are added to the table using these few lines of code below:

```
...
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> column : this.columns.entrySet())
{
    this.addColumn(column.getKey(), column.getValue());
}
...
public void addColumn(String name, int size)
{
    this.columns.put(name, size); //<--- set the column size
    this.defaultModel.addColumn(name); //<--- add the new column
}
```

`this.columns` is a `Map<String, Integer>` filled with column name and his size.

My goal is to set the column type for each columns of my table, for instance: I want the third column render as a checkbox because it's a boolean (indeed, not the default String field rendering). Took a look to [how to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) but I still haven't figured out how to deal with it specially "Using Custom Renderers" chapter and when it uses Array to determine the cell render (?) while storing rows inside the table. I use Vector instead of Arrays to manipulate data... I'm a bit confused...

How could I set a custom render on columns?

Comment: You can use `TableColumn.setCellRenderer`

Comment: Of course, but I can't understand how it works. Found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/TableColumnsetCellRendererTableCellRenderercellRenderer.htm) as a simple usage of `setCellRenderer` but I still can't understand in which way he is telling inside the `ComboTableCellRenderer` class that specific column must be rendered as a ComboBox but generally, I've clear what I have to do. Thankyou.

Comment: It's unclear from the code snippet, but either they registered a default `TableCellRenderer` for a specific class, which is returned by the `TableModel` or specified the renderer directly to the `ColumnModel`.  In either case, the code snippet you've provided does not show how it might have been done...

Answer (score 1):

override `getColumnClass()` in `DefaultTableModel` as below:

```
this.defaultModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex==2 ? Boolean.class : Object.class;
    }
}
```